# How can I make stream with fixed arguments along with varargs?

Tags: java, java-stream, concatenation, option-type, variadic-functions

Let's say we have the following method.

```java
void some(int id, int... otherIds) {

}
```

How can I create a single `IntStream` with those two arguments?

```java
IntStream.concat(
        IntStream.of(id),
        Optional.ofNullable(otherIds)
                .map(IntStream::of)
                .orElseGet(IntStream::empty)
);
```

It seems verbose. Do we have any concise idiom for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need to deal with nullable stream-source, you might use [`Stream.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) accessible with Java 9, which produces either a singleton-stream or an empty stream. It'll be cleaner than utilizing `Optional.ofNullable()` for the purpose of chaining methods on it.

```
IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(id),
    Stream.ofNullable(otherIds).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of))
```

---

Another option is to make use of Java 9 static method `Objects.requireNonNullElse()` which expects a nullable argument and a default value:

```
IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(id),
    IntStream.of(Objects.requireNonNullElse(otherIds, new int[0])))
```

---

And the simplest and cleanest solution will be a fail-fast implementation, that will throw a `NullPointerException` in case if array `otherIds` is `null`.

```
IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(id), Arrays.stream(otherIds))
```

A null-safe flavor of it (*credits to* @Holger):

```
IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(id),
                 otherIds != null ? Arrays.stream(otherIds) : IntStream.empty())
```

Comment: Varargs can be null.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Correct, removing the second part.

Comment: @OleV.V. My comment was regarding an earlier version of the answer in which it stated "varargs parameters cannot be null" (which I just wanted to clarify that they can),  Alexander Ivanchenko already fixed the answer well.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. Restored the removed part.  The decision to delete a fail-fast solution completely was a kind of strange spark in a sleepy brain. Personally, I think this approach is the cleanest one. Although it might not be helpful for OP (if they have, for instance, a part of a system that was designed to produce `null` to indicate the absence of data instead of an empty array, and therefore don't want to treat this case as abnormal).

Comment: @MarkusWeninger The array reference can be `null` when the caller passes a `null` array reference, but that’s not a *varargs* call anymore.

Comment: I’d use `Arrays.stream(otherIds)` instead of `IntStream.of(otherIds)` because `otherIds` is an existing array, so this is not a varargs call. Of course, the result will be the same. And when you want to handle `null`, consider `IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(id), otherIds != null? Arrays.stream(otherIds): IntStream.empty())`

Comment: @Holger I agree, from the perspective of self-describing code `Arrays.stream()` is a better stylistic choice than `IntStream.of()`. Thanks for this suggestion, I never paid attention to that before. Improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Alexander Ivanchenko has already mentioned three options.

Here's another one:

```java
Objects.requireNonNull(otherIds);
Stream.of(new int[] { id }, otherIds)
    .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
```

I think `otherIds` should not be `null`, and should be considered a programmer error. With `Objects::requireNonNull` it fails-fast.